# ShellCheck is carping that my expression is not in double quotes when it really is; why?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, shellcheck

I'm writing a bash script with the AWS CLI and `shellcheck` is giving an error that I think is incorrect. I'd like to try to figure out why its carping.

Here's the code, and error message:

```
for server in $(${aws} ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[][].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0]}' --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=${server_name}*" --output text);
                                                                                                                                                                            ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
```

I can't get the code to line up correctly in the SO editor but the `^--` is pointing at the `*` in the code.  This part:

```
"Name=tag:Name,Values=${server_name}*"
```

The error provides [a link to ShellCheck documentation](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2016) for reference but when I double check everything, it looks like I'm in compliance. :D

I am guessing that the `*` is throwing things off and I know that I can get around this by doing `shellcheck -e SC2016` but I'm really wondering what might be causing shellcheck to carp.

Any ideas?

Comment: As Joseph said I think it's more likely that your output is line wrapping and it's pointing to `*` but above it is \`Name\`

Comment: @jesse_b yeah!  when i shrunk the text of my terminal down way small, it lined up with the first quote on the `'Reservations...` part of the code.  thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a false positive, but it's not the one you think it is. It has nothing to do with the `*`, and didn't point there for me. It's upset about `` `Name` `` being inside of single quotes. For example, `` echo '`Name`' `` produces the same warning, because it thinks that you want the backticks to be evaluated, so it's warning you that they won't be.

Comment: ahhh indeed.  if i quote that part of the command in double quotes, `shellcheck` complains that i should use `$()` notation for the `Name` command, which is really a part of a parameter and not a command.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a formatted comment:

Pedantically, you shouldn't be using a `for` loop, but a `while read` loop:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r server; do
    : do stuff here
done < <(
    "$aws" ec2 describe-instances \
        --query 'Reservations[].Instances[][].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0]}' \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=${server_name}*" \
        --output text
)
```

`for` loops read whitespace-separated **words**, `while` loops read **lines** -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Alternately, use `readarray` to capture the output

```bsh
readaray -t servers < <(
    "$aws" ec2 describe-instances \
        --query 'Reservations[].Instances[][].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0]}' \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=${server_name}*" \
        --output text
)

for server in "${servers}"; do ...; done
```

Lastly, for long and unreadable commands, storing the options in an array can improve readability:

```bsh
opts=(
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[][].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0]}' 
    --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=${server_name}*"
    --output text
)

readarray -t servers < <("$aws" ec2 describe-instances "${opts[@]}")
```